# Why I need to use this bracket after get function?

Tags: python

I have a problem with understanding this code:

```
def dispatch_dict(operator, x, y):
    return {
        'add': lambda: x + y,
        'sub': lambda: x - y,
        'mul': lambda: x * y,
        'div': lambda: x / y,
    }.get(operator, lambda: None)() # here I don't understand this brackets  
                                    #  after closing get function

print(dispatch_dict('sub', 2, 4))
```

Comment: `lambda` creates an anonymous function. When you use get, the `lambda` is returned which is a function. Inorder to execute the function to produce the output, you have to invoke it using `()`.

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` function returns you lambdas (from the dict or just empty lambda). Lambda [is an anonymous function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) so `.get()` returns you a function. These brackets are needed to return you the result of this function instead of the function itself because with them the function is calling and returning you the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.get(operator, lambda: None)` returns function object - read e.g. https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/function-as-objects-in-python-d5215e6d1b0d, and adding () calls the function.

Maybe this simplification will help:

```
def add_lambda(x, y):
    add = lambda: x + y  # Note this is not PEP-8 compliant
    return add

the_function = add_lambda(31, 11)  # returns lambda function
the_function()  # here are your brackets, this returns 42
```

Comment: So, the_function = add_lamda(31,11) assign values from brackets to lambdas x,y and after this it assign it to add_lambda x, y  and in the next line we can induce this add_lambda()? @jbet

Comment: I don't think you understand the lambda function concept. There is nothing like "lambdas x, y". Lambda is a small anonymous **function** stored on variable `the_function`. This function has encapsulated values of x and y in its code.

In other words, 
    
    `def the_function:
        return 42`

is exactly the same as the thing assigned to `the_function` when add_lambda(31, 11) is called.